# (building cabal-install from git) Why Module `Distribution.Compat.Exception' does not export `SomeException'

Tags: haskell, cabal, cabal-install

I'm trying to compile hackport ( here is sources: https://github.com/Nensha/hackport ) with newer cabal but always getting the same Error:

```
[61 of 91] Compiling Distribution.Client.Types ( cabal/cabal-install/Distribution/Client/Types.hs, dist/build/hackport/hackport-tmp/Distribution/Client/Types.o )

cabal/cabal-install/Distribution/Client/Types.hs:33:12:
    Module
    `Distribution.Compat.Exception'
    does not export
    `SomeException'
```

according Distribution.Compat.Exception there must not be any problems and in must come from base but fails. So the question is why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that

```
Hs-Source-Dirs:       ., cabal/cabal, cabal/cabal-install
```

there are two modules `Distribution.Compat.Exception`. One under `cabal/cabal` and one under `cabal/cabal-install`. The latter exports `SomeException`, the former doesn't. But the compiler picked up the one from the `Cabal` library, which doesn't. Maybe reordering the directories in the `Hs-Source-Dirs` field would be a workaround.

Normally, when compiling `cabal-install`, the source directories of the `Cabal` library are not available, so the `Distribution.Compat.Exception` that gets picked up is the one from `cabal-install`.

Comment: but now I'm getting the same in Cabal :(